# Create a template in openshift cluster using fabric8io

Tags: java, kubernetes, openshift, fabric8, minishift

I'm trying to use fabric8 java libraries to interact with my local minishift cluster (openshift).
Basically my java application has to create a new project and create a template. This is due to the fact that in openshift a custom template has to be created for each new project.
With "create a template" I mean I need my custom template to be seen in the catalog panel of my openshift web console (or with [$ oc get templates] using a terminal).
I need to do the equivalent of "oc apply -f my-template-file.yaml", but with fabric8 libraries in java.
Here is a link to an example of usage https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/kubernetes-examples/src/main/java/io/fabric8/openshift/examples/TemplateExample.java

I've tried to do

```
        final Template loadedTemplate = client.templates()
          .load(TemplateExample.class.getResourceAsStream("/my-template-file.yaml")).get();
        for (Parameter p : loadedTemplate.getParameters()) {
          final String required = Boolean.TRUE.equals(p.getRequired()) ? "*" : "";
          logger.info("Loaded parameter from template: {}{} - '{}' ({})",
            p.getName(), required, p.getValue(), p.getGenerate());
```

But what I'm getting is a null pointer exception in method load() (line 2)
I thought it was becouse the path to the file is wrong, but the same error shows up even if i use

```
Paths.get("/my-template-file.yaml").toAbsolutePath().normalize().toString();
```

instead of "/my-template-file.yaml"

Comment: Where do you have `my-template-file.yaml` placed ? It needs to be in `src/main/resources` in order to be found by client

Comment: Thank you that was the problem, I did't know that. Now I get a different error, but it can see the file properly!

Comment: What error are you getting now?

Comment: Now, I'm trying to install a template, adding it to the catalog. But I'm getting:
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.Integer` from String "${PORT}": not a valid Integer value

The parameter PORT is described as follow:
 
- description: my port
    name: PORT
    required: true
    value: '8080'
 
I've tried removing quotes (value: 8080), but same error shows up.
I've found that issue in a git repo but I can't find any fixes for that
[link](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/issues/959)

Comment: I think you might need to use `process()` method in order to replace parameters

Comment: So I have to first process the template and next can I install it? 
May you give me a basic example code of how to do it? Sorry but I'm new in it and there is very few documentation about it.
Thx very much for your help!

Comment: Could you please try something like this and see if it works for you(line 37-41): https://github.com/rohanKanojia/kubernetes-client-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/io/fabric8/TemplateDemo.java#L37 ?

Comment: I've just tried.. I get the same error:
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.Integer` from String "${PORT}": not a valid Integer value

Comment: strange, I ran that sample (which I shared) and it worked for me

Comment: Could you please share your template spec?

Comment: I'm sorry I can't share the real file because it's confidential, but I can share a kind of copy of part of it.
`apiVersion: v1
kind: Template
labels:  
objects:
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: DeploymentConfig
  metadata:      
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
      deploymentConfig: '...'
      spec:
        containers:
          - env:
            ports:
              - containerPort: '${PORT}'
                name: http
                protocol: TCP
parameters:
  - description: My port
    name: PORT
    required: true
    value: '8080'`